# Ruby on Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really need some help, I am not a Ruby expert and I am trying to get an existing ruby app to run on my Ubuntu server.

I think I have done everything correctly but I keep on getting the following error:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, $GEM_HOME is not set,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check         
them for 'PATH=...' entries,
```

As well as

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is    
not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to ruby-version'
```

Here is the output from rvm info:

```
rvm info
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, $GEM_HOME is not set,
usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check    
them for 'PATH=...' entries, it might also help to re-add RVM 
to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',to fix 
temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.

system:

system:
uname:       "Linux ip-172-31-22-20 3.13.0-83-generic #127-Ubuntu 
SMP Fri Mar 11 00:25:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
system:      "ubuntu/14.04/x86_64"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
updated:      "1 hour 16 minutes 14 seconds ago"
path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  homes:
gem:          "not set"
ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"

  binaries:
ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb"
gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem"
rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME:     ""
GEM_PATH:     ""
MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"
IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/.irbrc"
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

THANKS!!!!

UPDATE

Thanks, I was able to set the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH values by using:

```
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

However when I change folders and go back, I get an error (see below) and the variables are no longer set.

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to ruby-version'
or ignore this warning with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore  /var/www/XXXXX/MicoBackup/.rvmrc',
 '.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.

Gemset 'XXXXXX' does not exist, 'rvm ree-1.8.7-2012.02 do rvm gemset    create XXXXXX' first, or append '--create'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203376/how-to-set-ruby-gem-home-and-gem-path

As the error message indicates, you're missing GEM_HOME in your PATH.

Start by making sure rvm is properly sourced in your `.bash_profile`:

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If that doesn't work, you can try setting `GEM_HOME` manually. See the provided link above.

Comment: Thanks, helped a little (I think), please see my update above.